# Get the code for dynamically updated html page in webview of an ios application?

Tags: ios, webview

i am trying to get the code of the html in a webview of an ios application . I can get the html code when the page is loaded in web view using UIWebView delegate methods. In the app,i have some dynamic contents which are added after clicking a button (html button) in that page.It is done through some javascript or ajax call. But i could not find any delegate methods, to detect the actions and changes in the web view . Could any one suggest me the way for getting the updated html page webview ?

Comment: You could use a javascript bridge and add in the callbacks to your iOS controller. https://github.com/marcuswestin/WebViewJavascriptBridge

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `UIWebView` does not provide any delegates for ajax requests. Anyways, I figured out a way how you can detect when an ajax request completed.

In your `ViewController` which contains the `UIWebView`:

```
#import <JavaScriptCore/JavaScriptCore.h>

- (void) webViewDidFinishLoad: (UIWebView*) webView {

    [self injectAjaxListener];
}

-(void)injectAjaxListener {

    NSString *jsString =
    @"var script = document.createElement('script');"
    "script.type = 'text/javascript';"
    "script.text ="
    "$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {ajaxCompleted();});"
    "document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);";

    [self listenToAjaxEvents];
}

-(void)listenToAjaxEvents {

    JSContext *_jsContext =  [self.webView valueForKeyPath:@"documentView.webView.mainFrame.javaScriptContext"];
    __weak JSContext *jsContext = _jsContext;

   jsContext[@"ajaxCompleted"] = ^(NSString *param1) {

       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

           [self showHTMLSourceCode];
       });
    };
}

-(void)showHTMLSourceCode {

    NSString *htmlSourceCode = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.outerHTML"];    
    NSLog(@"%@",htmlSourceCode);
}
```

**Note:**

- Don't forget to Link to the JavaScriptCore.framework

[image: Link Java Script Core Framework]

- Only works if the Website you're requesting uses jQuery

Hope this helps!

**Edit:** 
To listen to DOM Updates you can try to inject the following

```
document.addEventListener("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
    domChanged(););
}, false);
```

And then listen to the domChanged(); call like you did with the ajax requests.

Comment: hi @riik , thanks for your reply. The above code will be for AJAX requests. But there are some changes in my html page by using javascript , such as invoking a js function which will create and add elements to the DOM of html page. I have to get the html content after it got updated.

Comment: see the  **Edit:** in the answer. Maybe this would work for you.